# ¿Se puede usar LaTex en HTML5?

Tags: html5, latex

Necesitaría agregar ecuaciones a un código de `HTML5`, por ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>El teorema de Pitágoras</h1>
  <p>El teorema de Pitágoras nos explica la relación de catetos e hipotenusa</p>

  <!--
  Aquí necesitaría colocar la clásica ecuación, a^2+b^2=c^2,
  ¿se puede con latex?
   -->
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Se puede usar una imagen cuyo src apunta al  chart de google apis pasándole el latex urlcodificado, aquí un ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/204157/81450 , en tu caso sería https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=a%5E2%20%2B%20b%5E2%20%3D%20c%5E2 ( se agrega `a%5E2%20%2B%20b%5E2%20%3D%20c%5E2` después de `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=` )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HTML5` puede cargar imágenes vectoriales `SVG`, puedes usar un conversor `LaTex` a `SVG`.
Por ejemplo he encontrado este online: [tlhiv.org/ltxpreview](http://tlhiv.org/ltxpreview), el download tiene opción `SVG`.

Answer (score 7):

Se pueden escribir ecuaciones matemáticas en HTML5 con [MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML), pero el estandard no es muy popular, no permite escribir en Latex, y no es soportado por todos los navegadores.

Mucho más poderoso (permite escribir directamente en Latex) y popular (usado en https://math.stackexchange.com/) es [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)  . Pero no es puro HTML5, y el setup es algo más complicado.

Answer (score 2):

Te sugiero dos opciones ahi va:

1) Usar **latex2html** el cual te permite pasar tu código latex a un html básico, pero teniendo esto creo que lo puedes adaptar a tus necesidades. Algo que quizá no te guste, es, las ecuaciones lo pasa como imagen, pero todo depende del proyecto de estes desarrollando. En cuanto a su uso lo ejecutas desde el terminal :

```
$latex2html codigo_latex.tex
```

Esto genera un directorio con el nombre codigo_latex y dentro esta todo lo que necesitas como el *.css, *.html ... incluyendo las imágenes que se insertaran dentro de tu código (las ecuaciones mencionadas).
aca un ejemplo de salida.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2) No se si estas familiarizado con el [lenguaje de programación R](https://www.r-project.org/), en este lenguaje tienes una herramienta que se llama **[Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/)** (una verdadera maravilla, el cual te permite generar documentos PDF (el que más uso), doc, html, html5 ....  entre otros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y bueno en lo personal creo Vale la pena invertir tiempo en aprenderlo. Aca un buen ejemplo de lo que puedes hacer ([ver ejemplo](http://www.statpower.net/Content/310/R%20Stuff/SampleMarkdown.html))

Como podrás ver, la salida no es una imagen, como en el caso anterior.

saludos!