# ¿Cómo hallar el número de dígitos en una secuencia de números?

Tags: python, c++

Se puede obtener una secuencia de dígitos escribiendo la representación decimal de todos los números desde 1 hasta N consecutivamente como se muestra a continuación:

> 1234567891011121314....N

Por ejemplo, si la entrada es `15` la salida es `21`, porque `123456789101112131415` tiene 21 dígitos.

¿Cómo contar el número de dígitos?

Este es un intento de solución, pero dice que no funciona para todos los casos y no encuentro el caso para el que falla (el problema es para una asignatura en línea que me evalúa con varios casos de prueba, pero no dice en cuales falla):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n;
cin >> n;

int digitos = 0;
int iteracion = 1;
int longitud = 1;

if(n<10){
    digitos += n;
}

if(n>=10 && n<100){
    digitos += 9+(n-9)*2;
}

if (n>=100){
    for (int i= n; i >= 10; i /= 10,iteracion *= 10,++longitud){

    digitos += ((9 * iteracion) * longitud);
}digitos += (((n % iteracion) + 1) * longitud);
}

cout << digitos <<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en cual de los dos lenguajes? que intentaste hasta ahora? la respuesta es si, y te diria que es si para cualquier lenguaje. que intentaste hasta ahora?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El número 15 contiene:

- 9 números de 1 dígito (0 a 9).
- 6 números de 2 dígitos (10 a 15).

El número 155 contiene:

- 9 números de 1 dígito (0 a 9).
- 90 números de 2 dígitos (10 a 99).
- 56 números de 3 dígitos (100 a 155).

El número 1555 contiene:

- 9 números de 1 dígito (0 a 9).
- 90 números de 2 dígitos (10 a 99).
- 900 números de 3 dígitos (100 a 999).
- 556 números de 4 dígitos (1000 a 1555).

Supongo que te haces a la idea.

---

Así que el sumatorio de los dígitos de todos los números entre A y B se podría calcular así:

```
int numero;
std::cin >> numero;

int digitos = 0;
int iteracion = 1;
int longitud = 1;

for (int valor = numero; valor >= 10; valor /= 10, iteracion *= 10, ++longitud)
    digitos += ((9 * iteracion) * longitud);

digitos += (((numero % iteracion) + 1) * longitud);
```

A cada vuelta del bucle dividimos el `valor` por `10` y seguimos dividiendo mientras no hayamos consumido todos los dígitos salvo el último. También multiplicamos la `iteración` por `10` para que sea `1` en la primera vuelta `10` en la segunda `100` en la tercera (etc...) y la longitud de los números aumenta también a cada vuelta.

Por lo tanto, suponiendo el valor `155`, en la primera vuelta:

- `valor` es `155`, `iteracion` es `1`, `longitud` es `1`:

  - A `digitos` se le sumará `((9 * 1) * 1)` → `9`.

En la segunda vuelta:

- `valor` es `15`, `iteracion` es `10`, `longitud` es `2`:

  - A `digitos` se le sumará `((9 * 10) * 2)` → `180`.

No habrá una tercera vuelta porque siendo `valor` igual a `1` se acaba el bucle, así que se hace la última suma `(((numero % iteracion) + 1) * longitud)`:

- `numero` es `155`, `iteracion` es `100`, `longitud` es `3`:

  - A `digitos` se le sumará `(((155 % 100) + 1) * 3)` → `135`.

En total `9 + 180 + 135` son `357` dígitos.

Comment: Estaba haciendo el codigo en c++, y note que tu formula falla para numeros menores a 100. O tal vez no meti bien los argumentos, y por eso fallo. El caso es que trate solucionar eso considerando casos particulares cuando el numero es menor a 10 y cuando esta entre 10 y 100. El codigo resultante me sirvio, pero al probarlo con diversos valores, me dice que en algunos fallan. No entiendo cuales, que podria ser? te agradeceria si me pudieras guiar para solucionar mi problema. En la descripcion puse el codigo

Comment: Me alegra mucho que hayas podido probar el código :) ¿puedes darme ejemplos de datos de entrada y datos de salida para que pueda reproducir el problema?

Comment: Cualquier número de entrada está bien. Por ejemplo tus casos sirvieron, otros números cómo 15 que da 21, 5 que da 5 y demás que se me ocurrieron mirar sirvieron. Para comparar usé el código en Python que publicó abulafia. No obstante, estos problemas son para una asignatura en línea que me evalúa con varios casos de prueba si mi código sirve. Y me dijo que fallo en algunos casos, pero no me dice cuáles. No sé si me tocaría replantear todo el código

Answer (score 2):

La mejor solución es encontrar la "fórmula general", como ha hecho Paula. Una solución bastante peor es componer el número en cuestión y contar sus cifras.

Sólo como curiosidad, planteo un simple programa python que hace lo segundo.

Construir el número consiste en iterar desde 1 hasta N convirtiendo cada uno de esos números en un string y concatenando todos los strings. La longitud de la cadena resultante es la respuesta.

La iteración puede abreviarse a una sola línea con una *list comprehension*, y la concatenación la haría con `"".join()`, que recibiría como parámetro la *list comprehension* en cuestión. Así que el código queda:

```
def cuantas_cifras(n):
    return len("".join(str(i) for i in range(1,n+1)))
```

Ejemplos de uso:

```
>>> cuantas_cifras(15)
21
>>> cuantas_cifras(155)
357
```

Naturalmente para números grandes la solución no es eficiente, pues usa mucha memoria para almacenar el número en cuestión, lo cual no es necesario usando el enfoque de la "fórmula general".

Answer (score 0):

Ese tipo de secuencias (aunque antiquísimas) se las conoce como [Número Smarandache](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmarandacheNumber.html) Sm(n), siendo las mas famosas las [secuencias de números primos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarandache%E2%80%93Wellin_number) .

Aporto la versión Python de la fórmula para calcular [el número de dígitos en la concatenación de los primeros n enteros positivos](http://oeis.org/A058183)

[image: formula]

[image: formula]

```
import math

n = 15
Dn = int(math.floor(math.log10(n))+1)
DSmN = 0

DSmN += Dn*(n+1-math.pow(10,Dn-1))

for k in range(1,Dn):
    DSmN += 9*k*math.pow(10,k-1)

print "n =", n
print "d =", Dn
print "D(n) de Sm(n) =", int(DSmN)
```

---

Salida:

```
n = 15
d = 2
D(n) de Sm(n) = 21
```

Un snippet en javascript para jugar onlain

```js
document.getElementById('dale').onclick = function() {
  let n = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero').value);

  // cantidad de dígitos de n
  let Dn = Math.floor(Math.log10(n)) + 1;

  // cantidad de dígitos del Smarandache
  let DSmN = 0;

  // término inicial
  DSmN += Dn * parseInt(n + 1 - Math.pow(10, Dn - 1));

  // sumatoria 1 -> Dn-1
  for (var k = 1; k < Dn; k++) {
    DSmN += parseInt(9 * k * Math.pow(10, k - 1));
  }

  // resultados
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML =
    "<pre>" +
    "x sumatoria:" +
    "\nn = " + n +
    "\nd = " + Dn +
    "\nD(n) de Sm(n) = " + DSmN +
    "</pre>";

  // PdC usando un string y pedir el length
  let Sm = "";
  for (var x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
    Sm += x;
  }
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML +=
    "<pre>" +
    "usando string y calculando string.length:" +
    "\nD(n) de Sm(n) = " + Sm.length +
    "</pre>" +
    "<p>" +
    "\n" + Sm +
    "</p>";

};
```

```css
#resultado {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px dashed red
}

.wrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* CSS3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Firefox */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera <7 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* IE */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <em>Smarandache</em>(<input type="number" id="numero" value="15">) =
    <button id="dale">Calcular</button>
  </div>
  <div id="resultado" class="wrap"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo que podrías hacer es esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int num,contador=1;
    printf("Este programa te va a decir cuantos digitos tiene un numero. Introduce uno: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    while(num/10>0)
    {
        num=num/10;
        contador++;
    }
    printf("Tiene %d digitos",contador);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Actualizando:

Ejemplo hecho en C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int largo(int); // Obtengo el valor para la potencia de 10
int pot10(int);

int main()
{
    int num,contador=1;
    printf("Introduce un numero para generar la secuencia o serie: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    int i=1,sec=0;
    while(i<=num){
        sec=(sec*(pot10(largo(i))))+i;
        i++;
    }
    printf(" %d \n",sec);
    printf(" La secuencia tiene %d digitos.",largo(sec));
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int largo(int num){
    int contador=1;
    while(num/10>0){
        num=num/10;
        contador++;
    }
    return contador;
}

int pot10(int exp){
    int contador=1;
    int i=0;
    while(i<exp){
        contador=contador*10;
        i++;
    }
    return contador;
}
```

Ejemplo hecho en python 2.7:

```
def pot10(exp):
    i=0;
    cont=1;
    while(i<exp):
        cont=cont*10;
        i+=1;
    return cont;

def largo(num):
    cont=1;
    while(num/10>0):
        num=num/10;
        cont+=1;
    return cont;

def main():
    num2gen=int(raw_input(" Ingrese el numero n para generar la secuencia: "));
    secuencia=0;
    cont=1;
    while(cont<=num2gen):
        secuencia=(secuencia*(pot10(largo(cont))))+cont;
        cont+=1;
    m=" La secuencia es: "+str(secuencia)+"\n"
    print(m)
    m=" Tiene "+str(largo(secuencia))+" digitos. \n"
    print(m)
    pausa=raw_input("")

main()
```

Comment: Gracias! Pero la idea es hacer un numero que incluya todos los digitos hasta el valor que se digita. De esta forma, el numero 5 formaria el numero 12345 que tiene 5 digitos. ¿Como podria hacerse asi?

Comment: Ahí te lo modifico!

Comment: Hice el ejemplo en python para que vieras las diferencias, el problema en C es que si tomas valores mayores a 9, se te pasa del máximo número que puede almacenar un entero y no te da ya, obviamente, no pasa en python.

Comment: La pregunta está etiquetada como [tag:c++] y [tag:python] pero has respondido una parte con [tag:c].

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus NO ME DIGAAAAAAAS

Comment: @Zeugirdor Si, te digo. Y añado que [tag:c] y [tag:c++] son lenguajes distintos, así que una respuesta en C y otra en C++ pese as ser parecidas, no serán iguales; de ahí que señale que respondiendo con C una pregunta que está etiquetada (entre otras cosas) como C++ no me parece correcto.

Comment: Es verdad. Cómo está en c no me compila el código. ¿Cómo podría convertirlo a C++?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus, de ponerlo en c++, sólo le terminaría de completar el trabajo, si no buscó un patrón y yo ya le propuse una forma de hacerlo, no cuesta nada que el termine la parte que falta que sería pasarlo a c++.

Comment: @Zeugirdor ah, comprendo: le sugieres una solución en un lenguaje que no ha pedido para que tenga que buscar la solución por su cuenta en el lenguaje que sí pidió ¿Para qué pones entonces la solución en [tag:python]? ¿No era mejor poner una solución en ensamblador y que se busque las castañas?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus pasar algo de c a c++ no es difícil. Y la solución en python es porque justamente está la etiqueta python.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda. No pretendía que lo hicieran todo sino que me guiaran porque he tenido muchos problemas entendiendo la sintaxis de c++. ¿Que fuentes me recomiendan para practicar c++ desde cero?

Comment: @Zeugirdor "La solución en python es porque justamente está la etiqueta python" ¿y la solución en C es porque justamente porque no está la etiqueta C? No entiendo tu línea de razonamiento. Si no sabes programar en C++ no pasa nada, tu respuesta en python es buena, pero si la pregunta carece de etiqueta C no tienes motivo para responder en C.

Comment: @JOPanda Para practicar C++ lo único que necesitas es dedicación e interés :) para aprender cosas nuevas sobre las que practicar ¡bienvenido a SOes! Aquí encontrarás material interesante para aprender.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus sé programar en C++, sólo que no me parecía nada prudente dejar todo hecho.

Comment: Entonces entiendo aún menos tu línea de razonamiento: Sabes programar C++ pero decides responder en C, también sabes programar en python y decides responder en python; esos dos comportamientos son inconsistentes con lo que describes. Yo simplemente quiero remarcar que si la pregunta está etiquetada como un lenguaje: no debe responderse en otro.